# Drag and Droppable gridview in x axis

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, jquery-ui-sortable

Guys I have a gridview control.I'm getting record from database and adding to gridview table.I want to drag table's head and drop in x axis.While I dragging a table head,I want to drag its value too.I tried something like below

```
<script>
      $(function () {
          $(".gvLanguageClass").sortable({
              items: 'th',
              cursor: 'pointer',
              dropOnEmpty: false,
              axis: 'x'
          }).disableSelection();
      });
  </script>
```

I couldn't find what can I write to items attribute to make table head and its td value draggable?Can anyone show a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a library designed for draggable columns.
https://github.com/akottr/dragtable

You can import this files and all you should do is $(selector).datatable();

and done.